# Google Analytics embed API - access_token "REQUEST_DENIED" on other Domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

in my new Company i had to debug an error with the Google Analytics Embed API.
Following i figured out:

- We use following API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started
- In the Backend we make a Request to the O-Auth Service with the JSON Crediential to use in the frontend the authentication Method: serverAuth.access_token instand of the key or clientId

In the Frontend it worked correctly with one Domain.

For the Request against: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1s&callback=*xdc*._je5rc5&token=XXXXXX i got the Result:

```
/**/_xdc_._je5rc5 && _xdc_._je5rc5( [1,null,0] )
```

And the Second Request: 
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sLondon%20UK&7sUK&9sde-DE&callback=*xdc*._1aw0g9&token=XXXXX1

```
Return the Right Response: /**/_xdc_._1aw0g9 && _xdc_._1aw0g9( {
   "results" : [
      {/* Short Version */}
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
 )
```

But the same Requests on the same Server with another Domain got an error:

Request: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1s&callback=*xdc*._bllk9e&token=XXXXXX

Response:

```
/**/_xdc_._bllk9e && _xdc_._bllk9e( [0,15,0] )
```

And the Second Request: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4sLondon%20UK&7sUK&9sde-DE&callback=*xdc*._1aw0g9&token=XXXXX

Response:

```
/**/_xdc_._1aw0g9 && _xdc_._1aw0g9( {
   "error_message" : "Geocoding Service: This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
 )
```

Maybe some one had an idea what i could do?

Comment: did you enable the maps api in google developer console?

Comment: i think so because on the first domain it works, but i'm not realy sure. How can i check this?

Comment: are they both running the same client id from google developer console?

Comment: In my reproduced test-case i use the same Configuration on my localhost. One with localhost as Hostname, and the second with test.local.host. The second one got the error